# Google Webmaster tools: Total indexed = 0 & HTML improvements not updated

Tags: google-search-console

1) Why Google Webmaster Tools shows Total indexed = 0 for my website?
When I run site:ziedireizija.lv in google, it shows 59 results.
I have add both www and non-www to my webmaster tools. I have set a preferred domain to be without www.

When I open non-www in webmaster tools it shows:

Total indexed = 0

Ever crawled = 80

Not selected = 52

What this means? Why total indexed = 0. 
This is for website ziedireizija.lv

2) The second question is that Webmaster Tools has HTML improvements section. 
It shows Duplicate meta descriptions = 12.

I have updated meta description for those pages. However, it still shows duplicate meta description and I do see that Google has not updated these pages (neither meta description, nor page content). It has passed some time I have done this. Why?

And also Webmaster tools shows Last updated Dec 24, 2012, however, Duplicate Meta Description = 12 and I do see that those pages were not updated.
It could be somehow related with question 1.

Answer (score 1):

The urls on the HTML Improvements page don't update very quickly - often taking months to refresh.

To encourage Google to update this section simply use the 'Fetch as Google' (under 'Health' in webmaster tools) for pages that you know have been fixed and then click the 'Submit to Index' button when it appears.

Using this technique I usually see urls drop off the HTML Improvements page in a couple of days.